# htaccess redirect directory to query string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to find a way to redirect these urls:

```
http://example.com/some-directory-name/
http://example.com/some-directory-name
```

to this url:

`http://example.com?post=some-directory-name`

So far, I've got this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com?post=$1 [L,R=302]
```

but all this does is redirect me to this url and cause a redirect loop:

`http://example.com/?post=`

I thought that the [L] tag would cause the rule to not be applied again? Also, why is it adding a slash before the query string and throwing away the $1 part?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "why is it adding a slash" - The _browser_ adds the slash to make the URL valid. The _URL-path_ should be at least `/`, not _empty_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `RewriteCond` to stop redirecting when query string is already there:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)post= [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}?post=$1 [L,R=302,QSA]
```